# How to prevent darkening in overlapping line-heights in selected text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When text has a tight line-height, is there a way to control the opacity so that it does not darken where it overlaps? I have tried changing the opacity of the background color to `1`, but it is not making any difference. It is less noticeable if I change the background color to `yellow`, but I'd prefer to keep it something closer to the native OS color.

```css
* { font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; }

p {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
}

p::selection { 
  background-color: rgba(172, 206, 247, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, delectus incidunt, numquam sint saepe officia. Cum, porro! Animi atque, veniam voluptate, iure at quae, est dolores unde, accusamus nesciunt amet.</p>
```

The effect is not noticeable in Safari. I am concerned with Google Chrome.

#### How can I prevent this darkening on overlapping line-heights in selected text?

Answer (score 0):

An opacity of `1` is fully opaque and the default. Setting to a lower value seems to help:

```css
* { font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; }

p {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
}

p::selection { 
  background-color: rgba(172, 206, 247, .3);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, delectus incidunt, numquam sint saepe officia. Cum, porro! Animi atque, veniam voluptate, iure at quae, est dolores unde, accusamus nesciunt amet.</p>
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed lighter colors are a little better, but it's kind of a sacrifice.

Comment: @1252748 Well, you asked about `opacity` and you indicated that the default was too dark, so using `opacity`, the only solution is to lower it since higher opacities never lighten colors.